# Raspberry Pi 4 B stopped being detected over network

Tags: networking, pi-4

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 B. The network suddenly stopped detecting the pi. I tried using IP scanner, my router page and even gave a static address to my pi but my pi is not being detected. I thought that the ethernet port was damaged but when I connect it to my PC, the connection is being recognized. I can't even connect it to monitor to check IPconfig. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `I can't even connect it to monitor to check IPconfig.` Do you mean you get nothing on screen when starting up or that you don't have a screen to connect to the Pi?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || Add more details to the question. How you gave a static address to the pi? If you ping the `raspberrypi` hostname, what's the result? Are you sure that this problem happened suddenly and you didn't change anything/configurations? OS/Raspbian version?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *"the network" stopped detecting the pi* - since you are able to give the pi a static IP address without using a monitor, then you must be able to connect to the pi via ssh, therefore network is working ... by the way, ipconfig isn't a thing on the pi

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

From your statements:

- [The] "*Pi stopped being detected over network*"
- [You] "*gave a static address to my pi*"

It appears you're describing a DHCP issue. Sounds like your Pi is not being assigned an IP from the router's DHCP server.

### Your Troubleshooting:

It further appears that you proved the Pi's Ethernet port is working from your statement:

- "*I thought that the ethernet port was damaged but when I connect it to my PC, the connection is being recognized*"

### Analysis

And if you're testing the Pi's Ethernet port, it can be inferred that the means of connectivity you're using is wired.  If so, we can exclude wireless connectivity issues such as signal impedance/interference.

The nature of your network your Pi is connected to appears to be a *personal* rather than a *corporate* one from your description of "*my router page*". So probably can exclude ***802.1x*** authentication breaking connectivity.

And if your Pi's Ethernet port is working as you say- indeed you noted that the Pi previously connected before the issue- the Pi is capable of being assigned an IP address.  However, that's just not happening...

Lastly, since you ***DON'T*** detail other devices- ie, your "PC" & mobile phone- connected to the same network as Pi as also having broken connectivity, that implies the networking is otherwise correct & available.

***I suspect your DHCP pool of IPs might be exhausted***.  These days, **EVERYTHING** has network connectivity: Security cameras, consumer electronic devices such as TVs & refrigerators all grab IP devices. I've worked with companies both large and small that had issues with DHCP pools being. exhausted.

### Suggestions:

- Log onto the router and check the DHCP leases to see if the pool is exhausted.  If it is, delete a few leases and try connecting the Pi again.
- Make a local connection to the Pi by connecting a USB keyboard & mouse and use an HDMI cable to connect a monitor to the Pi if you can't connect to it via an IP address.  Then you can investigate the connectivity fault from the Pi's side.

You've not given us a very detailed description, so I've used deductive logic to infer the key facts & issues.  If I've made any incorrect inferences, please advise.  But all things considered, things looking very much like a DHCP problem from what what you've related to us.